# Elegant way to invoke multiple functions in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, function, dataframe

I am doing a data cleaning using Python. I have got the below workflow to call all my functions

```
  if __name__ == "__main__":

       data_file, hash_file, cols = read_file()
       survey_data, cleaned_hash_file = format_files(data_file, hash_file, cols)
       survey_data, cleaned_hash_file = rename_columns(survey_data, cleaned_hash_file)
       survey_data, cleaned_hash_file = data_transformation_stage_1(survey_data, cleaned_hash_file)
       observation, survey_data, cleaned_hash_file = data_transformation_stage_2(survey_data, cleaned_hash_file)
       observation, survey_data, cleaned_hash_file = data_transformation_stage_3(observation, survey_data, cleaned_hash_file)
       observation, survey_data, cleaned_hash_file = observation_date_fill(observation, survey_data, cleaned_hash_file)
       write_file(observation, survey_data, cleaned_hash_file)
```

So, the output (return statement variables) from each function is used as an input to the subsequent functions. All the functions return dataframe as an output. So `observation`,`survey_data`,`cleaned_hash_file`,`data_file`,`hash_file`,`cols` are all dataframes used in each function.

Is there any other better and elegant way to write this?

Comment: 1. Why the `ifmain` in the `main()` function ? 2. If you don't need all these functions elsewhere, you can try to divide them where it matters. To me, it looks like the lines from 6 to 9 are just one long script divided into 3 functions, and the lines 9 to 12 are the same.

Comment: have you tried to combine conceptually similar/same functions into one?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest - Yes, similar approaches are grouped in each functions accodingly. like stage_1,stage_2,stage_3. The logics are different, hence I have retained them as different stages

Comment: All the answers below are quite good but I am marking @Georgios Douzas answer as solution as it was easy to understand for a beginner like me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try iterating through your functions. It assumes that input of the current iteration has the same order as the output of the previous iteration:

```py
funcs = [read_file, format_files, rename_columns, data_transformation_stage_1, data_transformation_stage_2, data_transformation_stage_3, observation_date_fill, write_file]

output = []
for func in funcs:
    output = func(*output)
```

Comment: Can you please help me understand what does `func(*output)` mean?

Comment: It is the unpack operator i.e. unpacks the elements of the `output` list as arguments for each `func`.

Answer (score 1):

Create this class:

```
class ProcessingChain:

    def __init__(self, *callables):
        self.operations = callables

    def process(self, *args):
        for operation in self.operations:
            args = operation(*args)
        return args
```

And use is like this:

```
processing = ProcessingChain(format_files, rename_columns, data_transformation_stage_1, data_transformation_stage_2, data_transformation_stage_3, observation_date_fill)
data_file, hash_file, cols = read_file()
observation, survey_data, cleaned_hash_file = processing.process(data_file, hash_file, cols )
write_file(observation, survey_data, cleaned_hash_file)
```

Comment: A class with only one method next to `__init__` is just a function in disguise. See this classic video: [stop writing classes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9pEzgHorH0)

Comment: @RolandSmith This class is trivial at best, but when you want to implement further functionnality later on, you might feel the need to wrap your function in a class anyway. I find it conceptually cleaner, and more future proof to wrap things up in classes most of the time. But you do you.

Answer (score 1):

You can extend python `map` to accept mapping multiple functions, it will go as:

```
def map_many(iterable, function, *other):
    if other:
        return map_many(map(function, iterable), *other)
    return map(function, iterable)


inputs = read_file()
dfs_1 = map_many(inputs, format_files, rename_column, data_transformation_stage_1, data_transformation_stage_2)
dfs_2 = map_many(dfs_1, data_transformation_stage_3, observation_date_fill)
write_file(*dfs_2)
```