# Elegant way to invoke multiple functions using R

Tags: r, performance, function, dataframe

I have a set of preprocessing functions which I finally call to create the final dataframe. As you can see output of each stage is passed as an input to the next stage.

```
wrap_func = function(DF){  # Wrapper function which has all the above functions put together. 
T1 = transform_ids(DF)                                                          
print("Id transformation success")   #print statements are used for debugging purposes
T2 = transform_dates(T1)
print("date transformation success")
T3 = measurement_ids(T2)
print("measurement_ids transformation success")
T4 = oper_val_concepts(T3)
print("operator transformation success")
T5 = range_values(T4)
print("range capture success")
T6 = col_format(T5)
print("column formatting success")
T7 = missing_impute(T6,def_val)
print("Missing value Imputation success")
T7 = T7[c(                                                     # reordering the column display
"measurement_id","person_id")]
 return(T7)
 } 

DF = wrap_func(dfm)
```

Is there any elegant way to write this?

This post has similar scenario but it's in Python.[related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57570417/elegant-way-to-invoke-multiple-functions-in-python)

Can you help me to make this elegant using R?

Comment: Are you familiar with pipes (`%>%`) from `magrittr`, and packages like `dplyr`? This kind of workflow is pretty common in R these days.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have used `%>%` operator in my individual functions to perform operations on dataframe. Am new to R, so didn't really know how to use it for invoking them in this scenario.

Comment: `%>%` basically does exactly what you're asking for here, see https://r4ds.had.co.nz/pipes.html

Comment: Sure. Thanks will look into it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be:

```r
pipeline <- function(DF){
 DF %>%
 transform_ids() %T>%                                                          
  cat("Id transformation success\n") %>%
 transform_dates() %T>%
  cat("date transformation success\n") %>%
 measurement_ids() %T>%
  cat("measurement_ids transformation success\n") %>%
 oper_val_concepts() %T>%
  cat("operator transformation success\n") %>%
 range_values() %T>%
  cat("range capture success\n") %>%
 col_format() %T>%
  cat("column formatting success\n") %>%
 missing_impute(def_val) %T>%
  cat("Missing value Imputation success\n") %>%
 .[c("measurement_id","person_id")]
} 

DF <- pipeline(dfm)
```

where:

- `magrittr`'s `%>%` allows you to pipe the result of the left side as first argument to the next function.
- `magrittr`'s `%T>%` allows you to return the left-hand side value (because you don't want to pipe the printed string to the next step)
- the dot `.` at the end refers the the piped object (here the dataframe)

If you prefer to use `print()` instead of `cat`, be sure to put it between curly braces `{print("Hello World!"}`

If you are willing to give up the debugging messages (or integrating it into each unique functions) you can use `purrr`'s `compose`:

```r
pipeline <- compose(~ .x[c("measurement_id","person_id")], ~ missing_impute(.x, def_val), col_format, range_values, oper_val_concepts, measurement_ids, transform_dates, transform_ids)

DF <- pipeline(dfm)
```

Note that here functions are applied right to left (but you can have it left to right with the option `compose(..., .dir = "forward")`)

Comment: tHANK YOU. Will try. Upvoted. But still this one is as lengthy as the older one. Appreciate your help. Will try

Comment: You could probably use a more concise solution but it would be at the cost of giving up the printed strings. For instance you can use purrr's `compose` to create a unique function.

Comment: I am fine with not having the print statements.

Comment: I've edited my answer with `compose`, which makes it a one-liner!

Comment: So, compose works from `right to left`. In the above question, `transform_ids` is the first function that has to be executed?